# How do I insert record only if the record doesn't exist?

Tags: insert, sqlite, duplication

I have a `PaymentInformation` table

```
ID   NAME       Start       End
1    Tina       1/7/2014    1/17/2014
2    Alice      3/7/2014    3/17/2014 
3    John       5/7/2014    5/17/2014 
4    Michelle   7/7/2014    7/17/2014
```

I'm building my SQL query dynamically, like this:

```
SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder3 = "INSERT INTO " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE2_NAME + "(" +
                            "name, Start, End" +
                            ")VALUES('" +
                            tempName + "'" +
                            ",'" +start + "'" +
                            ",'" + end + "" +
                            "')" +
                            " WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM " +SQLiteHelper.TABLE2_NAME +" WHERE name = '"+
                            tempName+"' AND Start = '"+Start+"')"
```

Which gives the following result (formatted for readability):

```
INSERT INTO PaymentInformation(NAME, Start, End)
VALUES('Tina','01/10/2017','2/10/2017')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM PaymentInformation
    WHERE name = 'Tina' AND duration_start = '01/10/2017'
)
```

Is this how it should be done?
It shouldn't insert if Tina is already in the table with a Start day of 01/10/2017.

Comment: Hi Nelson, it's Java on Android.

Comment: Take a Google at "SQL overlapping date ranges"! The question arises what to do with the period  17/01 to 10/02?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a unique constraint & `insert or ignore`.

Create table:

```
ironforge:tmp phil$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-27 16:48:08
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table PaymentInformation
   ...> (
   ...> ID int,
   ...> name varchar(100),
   ...> start date,
   ...> end date );
sqlite>
```

Add a unique constraint on `name` and `start`:

```
sqlite> create unique index PaymentInformation_name_start on PaymentInformation ( name, start ) ;
```

Add a row:

```
sqlite> insert or ignore into PaymentInformation values ( 1,'Phil','2017-01-01','2017-02-02' );
sqlite> select * from PaymentInformation;
1|Phil|2017-01-01|2017-02-02
sqlite>
```

Add another row with the same name & start date, and it gets ignored:

```
sqlite> insert or ignore into PaymentInformation values ( 2,'Phil','2017-01-01','2017-02-02' );
sqlite> select * from PaymentInformation;
1|Phil|2017-01-01|2017-02-02
sqlite>
```

Comment: Note that if the ID field is set to autoincrement, then the IDs will still increment even if no row is inserted, so eventually the IDs will no longer be contiguous.

Comment: I see this too which is annoying

Is there a way to reset the counter to the last used to prevent these 'holes'?

I do the OR IGNORE to avoid importing duplicates and each time I scan my source and this leads to big jumps in IDs.

Comment: Use `insert or replace` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531035/how-to-do-if-not-exists-in-sqlite/23235141#23235141